# implementation of selenium as webCrawler

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a web crawler via Selenium in java. Previously I used libraries like jsoup and HtmlUnit to make them but recently I ran into trouble with javascript and ajax dependent pages.
After doing some google I think Selenium is a good option in the sense it perfectly  loads the page I want. But I am worried it will become too slow. 
Was Selenium a good choice for spiders ?? and are there examples of Spiders based on Selenium I can refer to ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), an open-source web crawler by Apache which is also good for multithreading though I'm not sure if it handles AJAX. 
Your other non-Java options are PhantomJS and CasperJS which are headless browsers. They run faster than Selenium because they are headless but they are still pretty slow IMHO.